# How to redirect the page on `refresh` without html compile?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am using the `dynamic` content all my html page. when user refresh the page, i require to redirect to home page. but error thrown my html page, the page is not redirected at all.

my html:

```
<div class="btn-sec">
      <button type="submit" (click)="goToArtcilePage()" [disabled]="productedSelected" class="btn">{{appProps['book.label.buttons.next']}}</button>
    </div>
```

redirecting like in ts :

```
 constructor(private store: StorageService, 
      private sharedData: SharedDatasService, 
      private location:Location,
      private router:Router) {

      if ((!this.appData || !this.appProps ) && Object.keys(this.sharedData.validationDatas).length === 0) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return;
      }

    }
```

but still getting an error as :

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'book.label.buttons.next' of undefined` and the page is not redirecting at all.

any suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

use get a property to access the data from HTML

```
get getAppProps(): string {
  return this.appProps['book.label.buttons.next']
}

<button type="submit" (click)="goToArtcilePage()" [disabled]="productedSelected" class="btn">{{getAppProps}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('url', {skipLocationChange: true});
```

The `{skipLocationChange: true})` property will change the route but url will not be changed. So the url always displays home url but internally the state are changed.

Another solution is to use Angular `RouteGuards`. Angular has `canActivate` and `canDeactivate` Routeguards. You can use their advantage for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with `{{appProps['book.label.buttons.next']}}`. The `TypeError` occurs as `appProps` is not defined till the data arrives.

Maybe use the safe Navigation operator `?` like so: `{{appProps?.book.label.buttons.next'}}`.